# Adding new tab to Docusaurus v2 navbar

Tags: docusaurus

I'm trying to add a new item to navbar using Docusaurus v2.
I have added an item 'Releases' next to blog in the same way as 'Blog' is added.
I also created a new directory 'releases' with a .md file in it.
Navbar displays the new tab but does not render the contents. It loads 'page not found' template. Am I missing any additional configuration?

```js
navbar: {
      title: "App",
      logo: {
        alt: "Logo",
        src: "img/logo.svg"
      },
      links: [
        {
          to: "docs/",
          activeBasePath: "docs",
          label: "Docs",
          position: "left"
        },
        { to: "blog", label: "Blog", position: "left" },
        { to: "releases", label: "Releases", position: "left" },
        {
          href: "",
          label: "Github",
          position: "right"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your new page under `pages/releases.js`. This is not a doc or blog page, so Markdown won't be supported.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I see you are one of prime contributors for Docusaurus. I feel supporting markdown for other tabs would be a great future enhancement. I would like to use the current Docusaurus work as one stop guide for our app: technical documentation, maintain release notes, provide help documentation.

Comment: Yay! I've opened a issue on Github: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/2882

Comment: The official docusaurus docs say you can have a markdown page in pages. There is even an example when you scaffold out the classic template.